# How to catch errors in a javascript façade for firebase 3.0.2 when authenticating

Tags: scala.js

I'm trying to write a javascript façade in my scala-js code to leverage Google's Firebase authentication javascript framework.  When authenticating to Firebase (after initializing), one will get either a Firebase User or an exception with a string error code describing the problem.  Specifically, I'm trying to login using an email and password as described at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword.  Providing a correct email and password returns me a valid Firebase user which I've "façaded" like so:

```
  @JSName("firebase.User")
  @js.native
  trait FirebaseUser extends FirebaseUserInfo {
    var emailVerified : Boolean = js.native
    var isAnonynous: Boolean = js.native
    var providerData: js.Object = js.native
    var refreshToken: String = js.native
  }

  object FirebaseUser {
    def apply(emailVerified : Boolean, isAnonynous: Boolean, providerData: js.Object, refreshToken: String): FirebaseUser = {
      js.Dynamic.literal(emailVerified = emailVerified, isAnonynous = isAnonynous, providerData = providerData, refreshToken = refreshToken).asInstanceOf[FirebaseUser]
    }
  }
```

And the Auth façade that contains the 'signInWithEmailAndPassword' method like so:

```
@JSName("firebase.auth.Auth")
@js.native
trait FirebaseAuth extends js.Object {
  var app: FirebaseApp = js.native
  var currentUser: FirebaseUser = js.native
  def signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String): Promise[FirebaseUser] = js.native
  def signOut: Promise[Void] = js.native
  def onAuthStateChanged(nextOrObserver: FirebaseUser => Unit, opt_error: FirebaseAuthError => Unit = null, opt_completed: Unit => Unit = null)
    }

object FirebaseAuth {
    def apply(app: FirebaseApp, currentUser: FirebaseUser): FirebaseAuth = {
        js.Dynamic.literal(app = app, currentUser = currentUser).asInstanceOf[FirebaseAuth]
    }
}
```

My code to invoke this looks like this:

```
// since 'signInWithEmailAndPassword()' returns promise, convert to future
val f1 = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(S.user.email, S.user.password).toFuture

f1 onComplete {
  case Success(fbu) => {
    fbuser = fbu
    scope.modState(_.copy(loginState = isLoggedIn)).runNow()
  }
  case Failure(ex) => println("Error signing-in to firebase, error="+ex.getMessage)
  case _ => println("Something else happened when signing-in...")
}
```

The success case works fine, but the failure case returns `null` when a `String` is expected that contains the reason for the error.  What am I doing wrong?  I suspect it has something to do with the fact that Firebase has its own Firebase.promise type and using the built-in scalajs scala.scalajs.js.Promise type is not enough--that I have to create a facade for the Firebase.Promise type.

I'm using sbt version 0.13.8 and scala-js plugin version 0.6.7

Comment: can you tell how you have solved. did you use firebase npm package?